# How to dynamically create a Func<T> when T is unknown in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, func, dynamically-generated

I have a task that returns a value, but I want to convert that value to something else (for example, from `string` to `int`). This is normally very easy to do, all I do is add continuation task which does the conversion and returns the new type as follows :

```
ConverterService converter = ...;
Task<string> originalTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<string>(...);
Task<int> conversionTask = originalTask.ContinueWith(p => converter.Convert(typeof(string), typeof(int), p.Result));
```

Problem is the types are unknown :( I have been able to generate the originalTask dynamically. Here is an excerpt off the top of my head :

```
ConverterService converter = ...;
// dynamically calling Task.Factory.FromAsync
var originalTask = FromAsyncMethodInfo.Invoke(Task.Factory, args.ToArray());
...

// now I want to dynamically call Task<string>.ContinueWith
var conversionTask = ContinueWithMethodInfo.Invoke(originalTask, ???)
```

What do I do now? I expect to supply it with a `Func<Task<T>, U>` (which is really `Func<Task<string>, int>` in this example), but how do I generate this dynamically?

To keep things simple, I just want to know how to dynamically create a `Func<T>` at runtime when all I have is a `Type` variable. Either that or a dynamically generated alternative to the lambda seen in the first block of code :

```
Task<int> conversionTask = originalTask.ContinueWith(p => converter.Convert(typeof(string), typeof(int), p.Result));
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I first created a method with the signature it's expecting :

```
public TOutput HandleTask<TTaskInput, TOutput>(TTaskInput task)
```

This method handles the conversion and exception handling. I then use Delegate.CreateDelegate to create an instance of a delegate to this method, which I then pass into the dynamic ContinueWith invoke.

Runs like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are little confused about what exactly you need... From the code you show I'd say your Func would have to return `object`, and you would have to handle the casting of object after the task execution. Going step forward, if your Func is the one that contains the logic to determine the return the type, you could return a made up class `MyResult`, that has parameters `ReturnObject` and `ReturnType`, then after the execution you would cast the `ReturnObject` to a `RetrunType` object.

Comment: I'm not confused, and this in no way answers the question.

Comment: @Anthony I am sorry that my answer is wasn't helpful, but you got here 3 people here giving you pretty much the same answer... It seems maybe you should modify your question to clarify the exact problem? Other than that the piece of code that Porges pasted for you seems the way to go...

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Task<object>` and pass the item around as an `object`. You can fetch the type of the object using [`object.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx). Here is an example:

```
void Main()
{
    var conversion = new ConversionService();
    var wantedType = typeof(string);

    Task<object> originalTask = Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(
       () => { /* test impl */ return 1; }); 

    var nextTask = originalTask.ContinueWith(prev =>
       conversion.ConvertObject(prev.Result.GetType(), wantedType, prev.Result));

    var result = nextTask.Result;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", result.GetType(), result);
}

class ConversionService
{
    public object ConvertObject(Type source, Type dest, object input)
    {
        // test impl.
        return Convert.ChangeType(input, dest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer the question. What you propose is a completely different (typeless) architecture; what I'm asking for is a direct answer to my current situation where I need to dynamically create/invoke generic constructors/methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate a `Func<TIn, TOut>` dynamically, because you need to supply logic for doing the conversion, and until the types are known, you can't supply the logic.

For example, if you're converting int to string, you might call ToString(), while if you're going in the other direction, you might use int.TryParse().  If you have a finite set of possible conversions, you could use some mechanism for a runtime lookup in a collection of already-constructed delegates, but there's no way to generate code that can arbitrarily convert a value of one type to any other type.

Comment: Please don't reply if you don't know the answer; not only are you wrong about the question, but you manage to be wrong about your own example! *Of course* you can perform conversions at runtime without knowing the types in advance as you can do very many other things at runtime without knowing the types in advance! Please downvote so this answer won't confuse others.

Comment: @Anthony obviously if I didn't think I knew the answer to the question, I wouldn't have answered it.  As m0s points out, if three people all come to the same incorrect conclusion about what you're asking, it's likely that the question is not well formulated.